# which is which's modifier

Tags: modifiers, parsing

In the following, is "yesterday" a modifier for "late" or is "late" a modifier for "yesterday"?

> Terry mills was dumped **late yesterday** while on a trade mission in Japan. [(ABC News)](http://www.abc.net.au/news/2013-03-14/abc-news/4571922)

Comment: *late* qualifies *yesterday*, bearing a [partitive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partitive) sense rather than  'tardy', or 'deceased' or 'former' or 'recent'.

Comment: @StoneyB: You should post that as an answer. I'd upvote it.

Comment: @matt I want to see if anybody can find something more interesting/generalizable to say about it. I don't know much about adjectives and adverbs.

Comment: @StoneyB- You crack me up...

Comment: @StoneyB, i can't fathom to where your depth could reach. Thank you.

Comment: @Jim The only interesting thing I know about adjectives is that the Romans classified them as nouns.

Comment: The Romans were idiots

Comment: @Jim Not really. A)Latin adjectives are declined just like Latin nouns. B)Latin adjectives (like adjectives in most European languages except English) are routinely employed as nouns. Accordingly, the Romans distinguished between *substantive nouns* (forms syntactically employed to denote a 'substance') and *adjective nouns* (the same forms syntactically 'thrown up against' a substantive to modify it). It's the same thing we do when we say that in *shoe salesman*, *shoe* is an *attributive noun*. The Romans were just more consistent.

Comment: If *yesterday* were analysed as adjectivally modifying *late* here, you'd probably want to insert a comma (and perhaps the word *only*) between the two, to make that (perfectly credible) sense clear.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Very nice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to resolve questions of this sort is to delete one term and see if the sentence still means the same thing. Let's look at this in context; here's the transcript of ABC's story:

> The Northern Territory's ousted Chief Minister will arrive home today. Terry Mills was dumped late yesterday while on a trade mission in Japan. He's been replaced by Adam Giles who becomes the first indigenous head of government in Australian history. Mr Mills is expected to touch down in Sydney this morning.

Now let's delete *yesterday*.

> Terry Mills was dumped late while on a trade mission in Japan.

This might be taken two ways: that the dumping took place later than expected, or that it took place tardily, too late to satisfy some unexpressed need. There's nothing to suggest that either of these senses is in play here, and in this form the sentence does not inform us **when** the dismissal took place—which is key to the story.

> Terry Mills was dumped yesterday while on a trade mission in Japan.

There's no ambiguity here; and the sentence does tell us when Mr. Mills was dismissed.

So what *late* does is tell us **at what time** yesterday this occurred: it is a [**partitive**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partitive) determiner which modifies *yesterday*.

However, as FumbleFingers reminds us, the collocation might in another context bear one of the senses in which *late* is the main term and *yesterday* served as a modifier; in this case *yesterday* would be a non-restrictive appositive and would be set off with commas or dashes, and would probably itself be qualified by some such term as *only*:

> Terry Mills was dumped late—only yesterday—while on a trade mission in Japan.